# Autogenerated XAML code is wrong?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've created a new WPF project and ony thing I've done is to add **WindowStartupLocation**, **WindowStyle** and **AllowsTransparency**. Then I deleted the autogenerated **Grid**.

So this was the result:

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="test" Height="768" Width="1024"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True">
</Window>
```

Yet I get the error:

```
Character sequence '</' was not expected at this location.
```

Why is this? What is wrong with the XAML?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might not be allowed to have no content in a window. Try adding some element to the window, like a `<Grid>` or `<StackPanel>`. If not that, it's probably just the xaml designer being incorrect. I have a lot of issues with the xaml designer saying there's an error but there really isn't.

Comment: It is probably because XAML schema - "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"(it is not actually accessible now) demands that `Window` have child content. Nonetheless, why would you ever need Window without any content?

Comment: As Yogesh said, XAML is a little slow to respond in Visual Studio compared to C#/VB code. If you're having errors that don't make sense, just clean & rebuild, or restart VisualStudio as a last resort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the XAML. Just rebuild the program, close all xaml views and reopen. That should fix the issue.

PS: Empty content is allowed in the `Window` or any `ContentControl` for that matter.